# httpsurlconnection not setting headers on addRequestProperty

Tags: java, httpsurlconnection

I have been stuck in a bit of a pickle - when running a httpsurlconnection call I am trying to set a series of headers however when debugging it is showing the headers I have added as NULL.

Code:

```
    URL obj = new URL(url);

    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection(proxy);

    //HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);

    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-GB");
    con.addRequestProperty("X-ApiKey", "xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx");
    con.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");


    List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", "xxxxx.xxxxx@xxxxxxx.xxxx"));

    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(os));
    writer.write(getQuery(postParameters));
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();
```

To test they are being correctly set I have added

```
con.getHeaderField("X-ApiKey");
con.getHeaderFields();
```

to determine whether my Header fields have been correctly set. However it appears they have not.

Responses accordingly:

```
Post Headers: null

Post Headers: {Content-Length=[11339], Connection=[keep-alive], X-Frame-Options= [SAMEORIGIN], X-Request-Identifier=[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx], Date=[Wed, 05 Oct 2016 16:56:49 GMT], Content-Type=[text/html], null=[HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request], Cache-Control=[private]}
```

Where am I going wrong in the above code which is not setting the headers correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `con.getRequestProperty("X-ApiKey")` and `con.getRequestProperties()`

The method `getHeaderField("")` returns the value of the header field from the **response** header. It is very confusing, so it should be better called `getResponseHeaderField("name")`

The output is not empty because your connection got already a response from the server after `openConnection(URL)` get called.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was loosing my marbles. I agree it should be labeled response header!